# Make Cancel Button bypass custom Validation using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, submit

i have two submit buttons on my mvc application.

1.

```
 <input type="submit" class="btnsubmit" value="Add Subscription" name="Submit" />
```

2.

```
 <input class="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="CheckBox()"/>
```

In document ready function i have this.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#form').submit(function () {
            var $fields = $(this).find('input[name^="chk_"]:checked');
            if (!$fields.length) {
                alert('You must select at least one record !');
                return false; // The form will *not* submit
            }
        });
    });
```

Basically one can submit the form only when atleast one checkbox is checked, but i want that user be able to hit Cancel and go back to home page. But right now, when i click on Cancel Button, the app tries to submit the page, and checks if any checkboxes were selected, which i don't want on Cancel Button Click.

Any approaches/ Views ? Thanks !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input class="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="CheckBox()"/>
```

change `tye=submit` to `type=button`. because, `type=submit` by default make a form submission.So it will look like:

```
<input class="cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="CheckBox()"/>
```

Or, you can change the button like:

```
<button class="cancel" onclick="CheckBox()">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: Damn, this was so easy :) Thanks !!